# Prove that if n is an odd positive integer , then $n^2\equiv1\mod8$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove that if n is an odd positive integer , then $n^2\equiv1\mod8$.

Can I prove by counter example by inserting several odd numbers?

My work:
I insert 1 into n. $8\mid(1^2 - 1) \implies 8\mid0$
I insert 3 into n. $8\mid(3^2 - 1) \implies 8\mid8$

Comment: If a counterexample existed, you could disprove this statement. There is no such counterexample as the statement is true.

Comment: You have to check each of the four odd congruency classes modulo $8$: $1, 3, 5$ and $7$. $5$ and $7$ follows from $1$ and $3$ with a small trick, but for this small size it's hardly worth it. Another way of doing it would be to write $(2n + 1)^2 = 4n^2 + 4n + 1$ and argue that $4n^2 + 4n$ always divides $8$.

Comment: Sorry not counter examples...I mean just show by examples like I have above or do I need to use congruence classes?

Comment: "Proof by counterexample" is when you're trying to show it's false. It's not sufficient to just consider the first few cases: You have to prove it for *all* $n$, and there are infinitely many of them.

Comment: @Nicholas You can _never_ prove that something is true for "every odd number" by testing odd number by odd number (the same for "every natural number", "every square number", "every real number" or anything else that involves more than finitely many). There are too many of them. Congruency classes will do the trick here since there are only four of them, but as I mention in my previous comment, it can be done without them.

Comment: True, it would be a long solution if I have to prove all of the numbers.

Comment: @Nicholas Not long but I guess, infinite!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check it out yourself:

Any odd positive integer can be written as $n=2k+1$

$n^2=4k^2+4k+1=4k(k+1)+1$

Now, for two consecutive integers, there exists one integer which is even.

I think you are done.

Comment: Is the work suppose to be done after 4k(k+1)+1? Do I need to say 4k would always be even and k+1 can be odd or even?

Comment: @Nicholas Absolutely not, $4k$ and $4(k+1)$ are both even, but observe that among two consecutive integers, there has to be one divisible by 2, so we can prove that $4k(k+1)$ is divisible by $8$.

Comment: @Nicholas If you still have any doubt, you can ask me, I will try to clarify them.

Comment: Ah yes you are 4(k+1) is even, my apologies.

Comment: I need clarification on this part: I am suppose to prove 8 divides n^2 - 1 and n^2 - 1 is actually 4k(k+1). So I need to prove 8 divides 4k(k+1)? Do I need to say 4k and 4k(k+1) is even as part of the answer, would that help me in any way to support the proof?

Comment: No, all you need to say is that $k$ and $k+1$ are two consecutive positive integers. So, clearly one of them is divisible by $2$, i.e., one of them is even. Now, $4(k(k+1))$ is most certainly divisible by $4$. And, from $k(k+1)$ you can get one more $2$. So, from $4\times 2=8$ you are done.

Comment: You get one more 2 only if k is 1. So I need to assume k is 1 and k+ 1 is 2, then?

Comment: @Nicholas Why? Take any other k. You can still extract a 2 even then.

Answer (score 3):

$n$ odd $\Rightarrow\, n = 4k\pm1\,\Rightarrow\,n^2\! = 8(2k^2\pm k)+1$

Answer (score 2):

If $n$ is an odd positive integer, then $n = 2k+1$, for some integer $k \geq 0$.

$$(2k+1)^2 = 4k^2 + 4k + 1 = 4k(k+ 1) + 1.$$

Clearly, $4\mid 4k(k+1)$. Now, one of the factors in $k(k+1)$ is even. So $2\mid k(k+1)$.

That gives us $(2\times 4)\mid 4k(k+1)$. So $$4k(k+1)\equiv 0 \mod 8 \iff 4k(k+1) + 1\equiv 1 \mod 8$$

Comment: How do you know 4 divides 4k(k+1) with a glance?

Comment: Because $4$ is a factor of $4\cdot k\cdot (k+1)$. Recall that $a\mid b \iff b = ak$ where a, b, k are all integers. $$\dfrac{4k(k+1)}{4} = k(k+1)$$ and $k$ is an integer, so $k(k+1)$ is also an integer.

Comment: Ah yes. That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the test only on a finite set of numbers, provided you use the right set and say *why* it is sufficient. Trying $1$ and $3$ is not sufficient, unless you justify why.

You can always write $n=8k+r$, for some $r$ with $0\le r<8$; of course, if $n$ is odd, also $r$ is odd. Since
$$
n^2=(8k+r)^2=64k^2+16kr+r^2
$$
you need to show the thesis only for $1$, $3$, $5$ and $7$:
$$
1^1=1,\quad
3^2=9\equiv 1\pmod{8},\quad
5^2=24\equiv 1\pmod{8},\quad
7^2=49\equiv 1\pmod{8}
$$
so the thesis is proved.

If you consider that $5\equiv -3\pmod{8}$ and $7\equiv -1\pmod{8}$, then you can see that your test actually suffices (thanks to Lucian for suggesting the idea), but without a motivation for the sufficiency your proof would be invalid.

Comment: It gets even simpler when one considers $5\equiv-3\mod8$ and $7\equiv-1\mod8$.

Comment: @Lucian Yes, of course. But I wanted to show how to do the verification with a test on numbers. All those that are needed, not just two as in the question.

Answer (score 0):

For every odd number $n,$ the integer $n^2-1=(n-1)(n+1)$ is the product of two consecutive even numbers, hence it is a multiple of $4\cdot2=8.$

Comment: Of course this common  argument already appears here many times, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/860/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4020294/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92286/how-can-i-show-e2-equiv-1-bmod-24-given-that-gcde-24-1/92291#comment217084_92291)

Comment: Indeed, such a simple answer should have been written here much earlier, and refered to in those later posts.