# Is $p^{2} \overset{8}{\equiv} 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I was working on an assignment on finite fields, and I think it boiled down to prove the following, for every prime $p>2$:

$p^{2} \overset{8}{\equiv} 1$

I checked it directly for small primes, and it seems to hold. Is this statement true? If it is, I'd appreciate help in reaching a general proof. 
Many Thanks!

Comment: This is true for all odd numbers $p$

Comment: In fact, for every prime $p>3$, $p^2=24k+1$, where $k$ is a generalized pentagonal number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, every odd number satisfies this property, since
$$1^2=1 \equiv 1 \,[8]$$
$$3^2=9 \equiv 1 \,[8]$$
$$5^2=25 \equiv 1 \,[8]$$
$$7^2=49 \equiv 1 \,[8]$$

Comment: OP asked for a proof.

Comment: @Oussema This is a proof.

Comment: You should clarify it.

Comment: @Oussema I let the OP understand by himself/herself why checking only the odd numbers before $8$ is sufficient to deduce the property for all odd numbers.

Comment: Fair enough, I guess.

Comment: Please strive not to post more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs

Answer (score 2):

Not only for prime numbers greater that 2, but also it's true for all odd numbers. For any odd integer $k$, the following is true: $k^2\overset{8}{\equiv}1$
The reason is that $k^2\overset{8}{\equiv}1 \iff 8\mid k^2-1=(k-1)(k+1)$
And because $k$ is odd, $(k-1),(k+1)$ are both even. Furthermore, one of two consecutive even numbers is also divisible by $4$ and since $(k-1),(k+1)$ are two consecutive even numbers, one of them is divisible by $2$ and the other is divisible by $4$ so their product is divisible by $8$.